# PostgreSQL jsonb_set function

Tags: json, postgresql

using postgresql db for persistence. one of my table's column's data type is **json** and stored data format is like

```
{
  "Terms": [
    {
      "no": 1,
      "name": "Vivek",
      "salary": 123
    },
    {
      "no": 2,
      "name": "Arjun",
      "salary": 123
    },
    {
      "no":3,
      "name": "Ashok",
      "salary": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to update any of `no` or `name` or `salary` of **1st Term object** only.

Used native queried to load and for better performance, I should use native query only for `UPDATE`. I tried postgresql `jsonb_set` function for the update, but unable to update.

I tried:

```
UPDATE table_name 
  SET terms = jsonb_set(terms->'Terms','{0,name}','"VVVV"',FALSE) 
WHERE some condition
```

and response message in pgAdmin tool is

> Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, x msec execution time.

Can any one help me with this one?

Comment: "*0 rows affected*" - means that your WHERE clause did not match any rows

Comment: where condition is correct .i just exclued for breavity.

Comment: If the WHERE clause did return any rows, the the result wouldn't be "0 rows affected". Run a SELECT statement with the identical condition to verify that